# Can I log psql time and statements to a text file (without the data)?

Tags: psql, logging

I am currently comparing performance of PostgreSQL with several other SQL systems. I am aware of the `\timing` option to turn on timing queries. However, I would very much like to automate the process of copying the statements executed and the query speed below it. I imagine there is a simple way to log this?

Let's say I run:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT itemID, prodCategory
FROM products
WHERE prodCategory = "footwear"
```

I want to automatically save into a text file:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT itemID, prodCategory
FROM products
WHERE prodCategory = "footwear"

SELECT 7790
Time: 10.884 ms
```

If OS Specifications are needed, I am using MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually **is** possible with UNIX. I just learned that you can use the:

> script *filename*

command to save everything that is printed on your screen. If timing is on, you can record the queries and the query time outputs.

To stop recording, simply type `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible currently..

1. Look at [`PrintTiming`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/2eb4a831e5fb5d8fc17e13aea56e04af3efe27b4/src/bin/psql/common.c#L631), it is using `printf`. While the [stuff that prints to the log file, is using `fprintf`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/2eb4a831e5fb5d8fc17e13aea56e04af3efe27b4/src/bin/psql/common.c#L706). My assumption is that the patch that provides this would be a couple of lines.
2. You would have to have the ability to suppress the outputting of the result on `--log-file`, which [we don't currently have](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/2eb4a831e5fb5d8fc17e13aea56e04af3efe27b4/src/bin/psql/common.c#L890). And in your case you want the summary logged `SELECT 7790` but not the actual data.

.. maybe in the future.